# Schedule iOS Auto-renewing subscription start in the future, like Netflix

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

How does the Netflix App on iOS start an Auto-Renewing Subscription in the future?  They have a 30 day free trial (which is outside of the scope of my question I think), but it turns into a subscription that you can manage (i.e. disable) from the Store Settings App immediately upon sign up.

I'd like to support a similar model whereby I could generate app-specific licenses that are valid right away, but also schedule an Auto-renewing subscription for start at 1 month into the future.  I did not see any option for this while defining products in iTunesConnect...it seems like all purchases are processed immediately.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388863/ios-in-app-purchase-auto-renewable-subscriptions-free-trial-option-not-available/16082399#16082399